# U1256 Underground Ticket - How many journeys permitted?

Tags: trains, tfl

I have an off-peak return ticket which is marked:

```
From: BRIGHTON
To: U1256 LONDN
```

The ticket does not say "travelcard" anywhere.

Just what does that entitle me to in terms of LU travel? I'm scheduled to arrive into London Bridge – am I then able to travel to any station within the zones listed making any necessary line changes along the way? I can't recall if you have to go through barriers in order to change line, thus making it count as an 'exit'.

Comment: You normally have the option to add a travel card to a train ticket. I suspect that the ticket is not valid for any Underground journeys, merely it is valid on any train route that will get you to those locations (ie, not just the London Bridge train you are planning to get)

Comment: @CMaster: AFAIU, a ticket to a London station of the traveler's choice would be issued to `London Terminals`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here is a forum thread](http://www.railforums.co.uk/showthread.php?t=66749) where it is claimed that `U1256` means a single connecting Underground journey in zones 1-6, whereas a ticket with an attached Travelcard would be issued as `London zones 1-6`.

Presumably what this means technically is that your ticket works as a single Underground ticket. Arriving at London Bridge you will go out through the NR gateline and then enter the Underground through its gateline. The ticket will stop being valid once you exit the Underground, except if you're making one of the [out-of-station interchanges](https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/publications-and-reports/out-of-station-interchanges) marked as valid for "magnetic" tickets.

For LU-to-LU interchanges it seems that this means only Bank/Monument, Wood Lane/White City, Hammersmith/Hammersmith, Euston Square/Euston, and internally between LU gatelines at Paddington and Kings Cross.

Comment: Thanks! I have also just managed to confirm this with National Rail - it is indeed an inclusive ticket for a Brighton-London journey PLUS a single underground trip (line changes permitted) anywhere from your NR station to any LU station in Zones 1-6.

Comment: @Jacob how did you manage to confirm it? Can you share that with us as an answer?

Comment: @CMaster I finally managed to get through to National Rail enquiries on the phone. They essentially confirmed the above forum post so for example my journey of Brighton-London Bridge-Shephard's Bush is valid on this type of fare provided I don't exit the underground between London Bridge and Shephard's Bush.

Comment: @Jacob: Too late now, but for Shepherd's Bush it looks like it would be both quicker and cheaper to buy a ticket specifically for Shepherd's Bush with a change for Overground at Clapham Junction.

Answer (score 5):

It is valid for one return journey. Here are the detailed rules for the ticket you purchased:

http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=BTN&dest=0786&tkt=SVR

Comment: This is misleading. Assuming the asker has a return ticket, each half of the return ticket is valid for a single (one-way) journey on the underground. If they have a single ticket, then that is only valid for a one-way journey on the underground. (That is, a single Brighton--U1256 ticket is valid for Brighton--London Bridge--Wherever but not for Brighton--London Bridge--Wherever--London Bridge.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby The asker has a return ticket (governed by the fare I linked), not a single ticket

Comment: Ah, I'd not noticed the comment saying they have a return: it's not obvious from the question. I'll edit that in.